# what あびて means?

Tags: english-to-japanese

Can someone tell me what "あびて" means? i'm trying to read japanese novel "ムーミン谷の冬" and there is sentence "でも, 月の光を**あびて**, 雪がきれいな青い色に光っていました." I think i understand everything else but not "あびて". Thank you for the answer!

Comment: What is your translation of the rest of the sentence? It helps us if we can judge what your current abilities are. If I said あびて is the te-form of the verb 浴びる does that makes sense?

Comment: Well my language is Finnish, but if i translate it into English it would be something like " But the light of the moon ______, the snow shone in a beautiful blueish/blue color." i'm sorry, i'm just a beginner and i'm studying japanese with two different language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 月の光をあびて, 雪がきれいな青い色に光っていました。

This あびて is the te-form of the verb 浴びる, meaning "to bathe in" etc. I don't know how familiar you are with the te-form, but it can have many different functions. In this case it adverbially modifies the verb 光る.  I would translate this sentence as:

> Being bathed in moonlight, the snow glittered with a pretty blue colour.